# Select div and on click function

Tags: javascript

Trying to select a div with "weather-info-temp" class and do something on click. But I get an error that  "document.getElementsByClassName("weather-info-temp")" is not a function... What am I doing wrong?

```
document.getElementsByClassName("weather-info-temp").on("click", function() {
// code
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array (like object) of elements and `on` is a jquery function.

If you have jquery, use

```
$(".weather-info-temp").on("click", function(){
    // do stuff on click
});
```

If not use

```
var eles = document.getElementsByClassName("weather-info-temp");
for(var i=eles.length; i--;) eles[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
   // do stuff on click
}, false);
```

Comment: It's not an array it's a `NodeList` but it's true

Comment: it's not an Array, it is an array (as in collection, group, etc)

Comment: @n00dl3 it returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.